# Eclipse PHP SIGSEGV When Opening Project File

Tags: java, php, eclipse

Eclipse is crashing every time when I attempt to open a newly created project file and I've done everything I can think of. This only happened after updating my system (Manjaro) and now even reinstalling eclipse and deleting all the files, I can find pertenent to eclipse it is still doing it.

It is very frustrating and I can't really work until this issue is fixed. Thanks in advance. I'm trying to open the files via the PHP Explorer View as well as the Navigator view (built into eclipse).

Eclipse Version: 4.6.1.

Java Version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_112"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

I've tried to revert eclipse back to the previous 4.6.0 but the issue still persists.

Here is the start of the crash log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f04a8da6cc6, pid=26036, tid=0x00007f054f909700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgtk-3.so.0+0x173cc6]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/taylor/core or core.26036
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The rest of the log is very long, and I can link it if needed but the character limit is not beg enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not an answer, is a comment but I've not enough reputation to make it.

I have the same problem with Eclipse Neon 4.6 JEE, Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_112, Manjaro recently updated and libgtk-3.so.0+0x173cc6 library.

To avoid being stopped you can try, temporaly, to run Eclipse with GTK2:

- Verify you have gtk2 installed
- Edit eclipse.ini and add:

  ```
  --launcher.GTK_version
  2
  ```

Comment: So far this works, although it is a temporary fix it is still helpful until the bug is fixed. For anyone else that is having this issue, install gtk2 (`sudo pacman -S gtk2`) and edit your eclipse.ini at `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini` and put the above code beneath the `--launcher.library` statement. At least, that's what worked for me.